# OpenCL: CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE in clSetKernelArg

Tags: c++, buffer, opencl

I am currently learning how to use OpenCL but I am having an issue with trying to enqueue a kernel to my queue.

The kernel is supposed to receive a float and 2 Buffer of type unsigned char and unsigned int -

```
__kernel void task2(float value,
                    __global unsigned char *chars,
                    __global unsigned int *ints)
```

My program looks like the following -

```
bufferA = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(cl_uchar) * alphabets.size());
bufferB = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(cl_uint) * numbers.size());

kernel = cl::Kernel(prog, "kernelTest");
kernel.setArg(0, 2.55);
kernel.setArg(1, bufferA);
kernel.setArg(2, bufferB);

queue.enqueueTask(kernel);
```

where alphabets and numbers are vectors. The program is built successfully but excluded since I think it'd be irrelevant to this question.

When reaching the enqueueTask portion in the program, I receive an error -

```
Error in: clSetKernelArg
Error code: -51 (CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE)
```

Unless I am completely wrong about this, the kernel takes in 3 arguments and I am passing in three arguments of float, unsigned char Buffer and unsigned Int buffer respectively. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say which of your 3 `setArg()` calls is failing, but I suspect the problem might be that the literal `2.55` is of type `double` while your kernel expects a `float`. You could try `2.55f`, or if that doesn't work, use a temporary variable of type `float` instead of a literal.

Note that `clSetKernelArg()` (the backend for `cl::Kernel::setArg()`) does not validate the size of buffer objects. So `CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE` only relates to size mismatch of scalar arguments, and for `global` pointer kernel arguments, `clSetKernelArg()` validates that the argument passed is in fact a valid `cl_mem` handle (and specified `arg_size` is `sizeof(cl_mem)`).

Comment: Your answer helped me, turns out it's simpler than I thought. 2.55 is a double type. 2.55f helped! Thanks!